# DVD ROM not working only in windows?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, partitioning, optical-drive, paragon

I have an Asus N53SV laptop, and my DVD ROM doesn't read any type of DVD in Windows.

I just installed Windows 7 from a bootable DVD, I think this problem occurred after I tried to change my partitioning with Paragon Partition Magic. I was trying to shrink, join and so on.

After this, Windows showed an error that Windows cannot find [weird address] on hard disk every time on startup.

Windows itself says the DVD drive works correctly and the driver is working properly, but no DVD or CD can be read. The DVD I'm trying to read is the same DVD which I used to install Windows some minutes ago.

I reinstalled Windows, but I formatted only the C: drive. I also have D:, E:, and a Linux partition.

Comment: The best course of action is probably to reinstall Windows, making sure to configure the partition during the installation.

Comment: Dear joeqwerty , I just reistalled it , but I only formatted C drive , I also have D E an a linux partiotion. is there any program to automatically check the hard drive for such these problems?

Comment: It sounds like a bad drive mapping: the CD/DVD is OK, but the OS thinks it is the wrong drive letter. Did you try to change drive letters in the registry yourself (Warning: dangerous)? There's plenty of results Googling https://www.google.com/search?q=windows+CD+drive+letter+in+registry which I cannot copy to an answer since it's gonna be trial and error.

Comment: I have included your comment into the question, but there's something unclear (please edit): Do you "have D E **on** / **as** a Linux partition" or "have D E **and** a Linux partition".

Comment: And what's the *weird address*?

Comment: @BehroozA try mark partition as active for c: drive from disk management.

Answer (score 1):

If reinstalling the driver doesn't work, try reinstalling the physical drive. (Let Windows get used to no drive, and then install it to have it detected as a new one.)

If you don't want to buy a different drive, maybe running Windows on a virtual machine in a Linux or BSD distro will suffice. [Wine](http://www.winehq.org/) can also help.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this happen before on XP and apparently, it can potentially happen to Win7 as well.

Here's Microsoft's solution:
http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=KB;EN-US;314060

Comment: I tried it before , it says there is no CD/DVD in the drive! the same DVD in drive is tested with another laptop here

Comment: Ah the upper filter problem. Yeah, it could happen to Vista and 7 too. But in upper filter problem, you won't even see the drive in explorer.

Answer (score 0):

GST's solution worked for me. It led me to [this page about the Windows Hardware and Devices troubleshooter](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/Open-the-Hardware-and-Devices-troubleshooter), stating:

> Open the Hardware and Devices troubleshooter by clicking the **Start** button [image: Picture of the Start button], and then clicking **Control Panel**.  In the search box, type **troubleshooter**, and then click **Troubleshooting**. 
>   Under **Hardware and Sound**, click **Configure a device**.[image: UAC shield]‌  If you're prompted for an administrator password or confirmation, type the password or provide confirmation.

Comment: please try to write here in SuperUser the relevant steps and procedures included on the provided link. Also, do not use links as plain answers. If the link ever gets broken, so does your whole answer.